# Finding DOM elements containing a value for any attribute using CSS Selectors

Tags: java, scala, dom, css-selectors, jsoup

I'm trying to fetch any DOM elements that contain a given phrase in a value of ***any of its attributes***.

For example: detecting any string containing .jpg extension in any of the DOM element's attributes, not just a known one (src for example).

Is there any way to do it with Jsoup / CSS selectors? Or should I manually traverse the whole dom?

If I knew the attribute, I could just match any element with `[attr*='.jpg']` but it seems there is no "wildcard" for the attribute part of CSS selectors.

Comment: You could try to use XPATH for such things but i'd really suggest to traverse the DOM tree by yourself. (That way you know that your code really does what you expect from it)